# Python Selenium. Can't click on a button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automated-tests

Hi I'm trying to click on this button "Next" on this link:
https://www.sneakql.com/en-GB/launch/culturekings/womens-air-jordan-1-high-og-court-purple-au/register

I tried this but It didn't work...

```
chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/div/button').click();
```

I'm getting this:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-fullWidth" tabindex="0" type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (456, 870). Other element would receive the click: <div class="jss3" style="flex: 1 0 300px; margin: 15px;">...</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: i'm getting this

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-fullWidth" tabindex="0" type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (456, 870). Other element would receive the click: <div class="jss3" style="flex: 1 0 300px; margin: 15px;">...</div>

Comment: Show your code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click it as I suggested in another your question, with `xpath` and waiting till it's clickable:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click()
```

But before clicking this button, you will have to accept the cookies:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'AGREE')]"))).click()
```

For this you will need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 2):

"Agree" button and "Next button" has similar class name and so "Agree" button is receiving the click.

See if this works:-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[contains(@class,'MuiButton-containedPrimary') and @type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: Same problem as before : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained MuiButton-containedPrimary MuiButton-fullWidth" tabindex="0" type="submit">...</button> is not clickable at point (456, 870). Other element would receive the click: <div class="jss3" style="flex: 1 0 300px; margin: 15px;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: You have to accept the cookies by this xpath ".//button[@id='rcc-confirm-button']" and then try the xpath for Next button

Comment: You were very close to the full answer. Click did not work because of cookies button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

next_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="MuiButton-label" and contains(text(),"Next")]')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_btn).perform()
```

If this doesn't help - try adding a simple

```
time.sleep(5)
```

before clicking on that button

Comment: it does not locate the button : selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@class="MuiButton-label" and contains(text()," because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@class="MuiButton-label" and contains(text(),"' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: You are right, sorry. My mistake with copy-pasting the locator. I've corrected the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can just click with JS

```
button = chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/div/div/button')
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

Comment: As soon as DOM structure changes, even this approach will stop working. It is recommended to not use full xpath in UI automation because it's unstable. But is is a good option when Selenium's click does not work even with short locators.